# Endpoint configuration missing for this service while using aws S3

Tags: go, amazon-s3

Error : Endpoint configuration missing for this service while using aws S3 with Golang

```golang
session, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(
    session.Options{
        Profile: "default",
        Config: aws.Config{
            Credentials:      credentials.NewStaticCredentials("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX", ""),
            Region:           aws.String(AWS_S3_REGION),
            Endpoint:         aws.String("XXXXXXX"),
// ---------^^^^^^^^
            DisableSSL:       aws.Bool(false),
            S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true),
        },
    },
)
```

What should be value of Endpoint, if we connecting to S3 from golang?
where can I find the endpoint in AWS S3?

I tried locally with S3 emulator, it's working fine, but it's not working with S3 aws cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of Endpoint as per the sdk documentation - [AWS Go SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#Config)

```
// An optional endpoint URL (hostname only or fully qualified URI)
// that overrides the default generated endpoint for a client. Set this
// to `nil` or the value to `""` to use the default generated endpoint.
//
// Note: You must still provide a `Region` value when specifying an
// endpoint for a client.
Endpoint *string
```

This essentially means you can specify the endpoint just like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new AWS session with a custom endpoint URL
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:   aws.String("us-west-2"),
        Endpoint: aws.String("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"),
    }))

    // Create an Amazon S3 client using the custom endpoint
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    // List all the buckets in the S3 account
    resp, err := svc.ListBuckets(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listing buckets:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Buckets:")
    for _, bucket := range resp.Buckets {
        fmt.Printf("* %s created on %s\n",
            aws.StringValue(bucket.Name), aws.TimeValue(bucket.CreationDate))
    }
}
```

Comment: The endpoint URL should not contain a bucket name I guess.
or can you help me to understand whats S3 is in your endpoint URL??